# Solr multi-select facets occurs bad request error

Tags: search

I faced with a weird problem using apache solr faceting search. While selecting two facet constraints, solr respond with 400 error:

> "400" Status: null: null HTTP ERROR 400
>
> Problem accessing /solr/project/select. Reason:
>
> null

Basically I have one index configured and number of fields indexed inside. I'm using facet for "content type" field. There is no problem at all when only one facet constraint is selected.

> http://localhost:8983/solr/project/select?fl=item_id,score&fq={!tag=facet:type}ss_type:"system"&start=0&rows=10&sort=ds_created
>   desc&facet=true&facet.sort=count&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1&facet.missing=false&facet.field={!ex=facet:type}ss_type&f.ss_type.facet.limit=50&wt=json&json.nl=map&q.alt=(ss_search_api_language:"sv")
>   (index_id:"project_nodes_index") (hash:gf1tmd)

Problem starts where two constraints are selected:

> http://localhost:8983/solr/project/select?fl=item_id,score&start=0&rows=10&sort=ds_created
>   desc&facet=true&facet.sort=count&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1&facet.missing=false&facet.field={!ex=facet:type}ss_type&f.ss_type.facet.limit=50&wt=json&json.nl=map&q.alt=(ss_search_api_language:"sv")
>   ((({!tag=facet:type}ss_type:"system") OR
>   ({!tag=facet:type}ss_type:"product")))
>   (index_id:"project_nodes_index") (hash:gf1tmd)

Standart modules are used:
* search_api_solr
* search_api
* facetapi

Solr version 3.6.2

Comment: having exactly the same issue here :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update to the latest dev version.

For more info you could check this issue:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2290601